# Why don't Standard C Libraries need to be divided into a header and implementation file?

Tags: c, class, include, c-standard-library

When creating a class in C++, or an *equivalent* in C with *structs*, it is always a good idea to divide it into two files: a header file (for declarations) and an implementation file (for actually defining methods and such).

This is done because method-definitions can conflict if they exist in multiple files (and include guards can't prevent that, because macros only exist in the file that they were defined in, and are copied over to files that include them; include guards protect from including the same header multiple times in *the same file*)

However, it seems as though many of the standard C libraries actually define things. Lets use `stdlib.h` in C as an example. This library seems to define a method called `malloc` for allocating memory. But (of course) if I include `stdlib.h` in multiple files, no method-definitions of malloc seem to conflict.

In other words, if I were to create my own library with my own memory allocation method (assume it is not a macro function) I would have to declare it in `mylib.h` and actually define it in `mylib.c` but this does not appear to apply to `stdlib.h` for some reason.

How does this work? How come Standard C Libraries can do this but user-defined headers (unfortunately, in my opinion) can't?

Comment: The standard library headers only declare functions. The functions are defined in the library, which is usually linked automatically (except for the math functions), but you can normally ask the compiler not to do so if you are compiling for a standalone environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard C library has already been compiled into a library, which might be called something like `libc.so` or `MSVCRT100.DLL`.  You can provide this file instead of the `*.o` or `*.obj` files that the compiler would generate from your `*.c` file.  The compiler links this runtime library with every program silently and automatically.

This is how other libraries work, too.  If you have the compiled OpenSSL library, you link to the library and `#include` the header file in your source code to see its interfaces, such as the function names and prototypes. You don't need the other source files that the library was built from.

You can download the source code to many implementations of the C library, such as GNU libc.  The runtime is, in fact, implemented in `*.c` files, which you can read, modify, recompile and submit patches to the maintainers for, but it's compiled to a shared library ahead of time and your compiler links to that.

Comment: Three things: Is there any way to see the source code of the standard C library? Secondly, if a header *only* contains macro definitions, is it bad practice to skip creating an implementation file? Thirdly, is it okay to store the implementation code in the header in the form of a giant macro, so that one can *easily* implement that library simply by using that macro in the implementation file? Answer those questions in the comments and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: This isn't the best way to ask follow-up questions, but OK. 1: You can download an open-source (They would rather I call it Libre) library such as GNU libc from GNU.org. To see Microsoft's, apply for a dev job at Microsoft.

Comment: 2: I don't see why that would be a bad practice. Why create files that serve no useful purpose? I sometimes make configuration files that contain only macros. This is more common for C++ template libraries.

Comment: 3: That is a terrible idea. :) But it's a good exercise to think through the reasons.

Comment: Not all of the runtime is implemented in C, and some if it has multiple implementations.

Comment: @ncl It's likely that whatever's not in C is in inline assembler within the `*.c` files, but there could be exceptions. In any case, if you download the glibc source package, it should contain all the files you need to compile the library.

Answer (score 1):

`stdlib.h` is **NOT** a library. Instead, it's the header file for a big library, which defines a method called `malloc` for allocating memory.

That is:

`stdlib.h` ONLY contains the declarations (prototypes) of its members.

The library itself (`*.a` or `*.so` in Linux-OS) contains the actual definition (implementation) of `malloc` method (and others).

> but this does not appear to apply to stdlib.h for some reason.

It does, but the only difference is that, in your example, you depend on a source file (i.e., `mylib.c`) to build a library. Whereas in the standard C case you used in your question, it is already a library that should be linked to your program if you included its header file (i.e., `stdlib.h`).